# What does the "~0x80" mean in libxcb code sample?

Tags: x11, xcb

```
switch (event->response_type & ~0x80)
```

From [this sample code](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/), what does the `~0x80` mean?

Answer (score 8):

I had this same question quite recently. The answer can be found in [X Window System Protocol, Event Format](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#event_format):

> Every event contains an 8-bit type code. The most significant bit in this code is set if the event was generated from a SendEvent request.

Bitwise-and of `~0x80` and the event type code (which lives in the `response_type` field of the event struct) clears that bit such that the event code can then be correctly matched no matter the origin (X Server itself where that bit is not set or another client, e.g. a Window Manager, where it *is* set) to expected codes.

Comment: I'm surprised there doesn't exist a macro for this. How hard is it to do something like `#define XCB_EVENT_MASK (~0x80)`